# Unable to create task on Salesforce1: Task Record Type ID: this ID value isnt valid for the user

Tags: salesforce1-app, record-type, tasks, id, invalid

While creating a new task using the 'New Task' button in the open activities section of an objects page layout using salesforce1 app, it throws an error 'Task Record Type ID: this ID value isn't valid for the user:'. The same button from the same section of the object using the standard web page login works just fine, user is able to create a task without an issue.

What am I missing here? Does salesforce1 require additional configuration for record types to be accessible.

Verified the following:

- Users have access to the record type in the profile
- Appropriate page layout and record type is assigned to the user.
- Button is accessible to all users
- Can create using the standard salesforce login
  (test.salesforce.com/login.salesforce.com)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Go to:
Setup > Administer > Manage Users > Profiles > System Admin > Object Settings >
Task > Tick the appropriate "Assigned Record Types"

I faced your problem before on Case and this is how I fixed my error and I believe the error should be similar to in case:

[image]

Do let me know if it worked for you.
Cheers.